# How to generate and display tags in treemacs (for JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, tags, treemacs

I'd like to generate a set of tags and then view them in Treemacs, ideally whenever I open a file that I can generate tags for.

The [docs for Treemacs' tag view](https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs#tag-view) say:

> Treemacs is able to display
>   not only the file system, but also tags found in individual files. The
>   tags list is sourced using emacs’ builtin imenu functionality, so all
>   file types that emacs can generate an imenu index for are supported.
>
> Imenu caches its result, so to avoid stale tag lists setting
>   imenu-auto-rescan to t is recommended. Tags generated with the help of
>   semantic-mode are likewise supported.

I looked around and it appears that js-mode does offer imenu support.

I'm at a loss for how to actually connect these two - how do I get js-mode to create the imenu index so that treemacs can actually use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[js2-mode](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode) generates an imenu index that Treemacs displays.

Comment: I'm sorry for the total noob questions, but - how do I get js2-mode to generate the imenu?  Once it's generated does Treemacs automatically display that?  (If so - how does Treemacs know to look for the imenu?)

Comment: The imenu generation should happen automatically. You can see it in treemacs by putting point on, say, a js file and hitting `TAB` -- it will show the items it found in that file such as variables, functions, etc.

Comment: Hey, that worked!  Thanks for the help!